# magento sort attribute option collection by position?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

Greetings,

I am trying to sort an array of attribute option values by their "position" as entered in the manage attributes panel. I seem to have tried everything, does anyone know how this is possible?

I thought for sure this would work:

```
    $_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
        ->setStoreFilter(0)
        ->setAttributeFilter($_productAttribute->getId())
        ->addAttributeToSort('position')
        ->load();
```

But it didn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've alredy been experienced with addAttributeToSort in a previous project: maybe this function doesn't works until today try with setOrder('columname') or try to update your magento to last version

Answer (score 0):

Working great. In Magento 1.6 + use `setOrder('sort_order')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load( $code, 'attribute_code');
$option_col = Mage::getResourceModel( 'eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
 ->setAttributeFilter( $attribute->getId() )
 ->setStoreFilter()
 ->setPositionOrder( 'ASC' );
$option_col->getSelect()->order('main_table.sort_order '.$orderby);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the begining of app/design/frontend/default/default/template/manapro/filtercheckboxes/items.phtml add following code:

```
function cmp($a, $b){
  if ($a == $b)
    return 0;
  return ($a['position'] < $b['position']) ? -1 : 1;
}
$array = $this->getItems();
usort($array, "cmp");
```

And replace $this->getItems() with  $array in foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

As it eav collection it load load join query to collection and using load function. so if you add  order after

```
Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
```

just like:

```
$_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')->getSelect()->order('main_table.sort_order '.$orderby);
        $_collection->setStoreFilter(0)
        ->setAttributeFilter($_productAttribute->getId())
        ->load();
```