# How do I get the Position of an Attribute-Option in Magento?

Tags: php, sorting, magento, attributes

I've got the following problem. In an extra module, I want to sort the options of an attribute, based on their position. When I try to get the Option of an Attribute, I can get the Id and the Label, but there is nothing mor ein that object.

I can do, for example, this:

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($code)->getOptionsText($value):
```

Or just getOptionId($value), but there is nothing to get the Position, which is editable in the backend. So, how to get this? Havn't found anything (useful) on the net yet.

(Also the similar question [magento sort attribute option collection by position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068201/magento-sort-attribute-option-collection-by-position) doesnt give any help)

EDIT:
What I managed to do, is doing a direct SQL statement, like this:

```
SELECT sort_order FROM mag_eav_attribute_option WHERE option_id = 114 AND attribute_id = 533;
```

But I think, there is a better option to get that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself and want to share it with you.

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load( $code, 'attribute_code');
$option_col = Mage::getResourceModel( 'eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
 ->setAttributeFilter( $attribute->getId() )
 ->setStoreFilter()
 ->setPositionOrder( 'ASC' );
$option_col->getSelect()->order('main_table.sort_order '.$orderby);
```

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  awesome.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually quite simple if you take a look @ `Mage_Eav_Block_Adminhtml_Attribute_Edit_Options_Abstract`

```
$attributeId = 230;
$options = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
            ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
            ->setPositionOrder('desc', true)
            ->load();

foreach($options as $opt){
    Mage::log($opt->getSortOrder());
}
```

I see you came up with something similar already but I thought I would post this as it may be helpful to others.

Comment: +1 I liked your solution very much wanted to add to it that we can do $opt->getData() in the loop and we will have the lable for each position too which will be pretty useful

Answer (score 0):

Start to debug then:

```
print_r($_product->getResource()->getAttribute($code));
print_r($_product->getResource()->getAttribute($code)->getData());
print_r(get_class_methods($_product->getResource()->getAttribute($code)));
```

Comment: Of course I did that already. As I said, the Attribute itself only has got getOptionId and getOptionText, but not the position.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have your attribute code `$code` and your attribute option value `$value`. Then you can get the corresponding sort order like that:

```
$source = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($code)->getSource();
$optionId = $source->getOptionId($product->getData($code));
$optionSortOrder = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
                    ->setIdFilter($_optionId)
                    ->getFirstItem()
                    ->getSortOrder();
```

Answer (score -1):

From: http://www.phptechi.com/getting-product-attributes-values-and-labels.html

How to fetch attribute value sort order?

Here is the Quick and Easy way using SQL to get attribute value sort positing.
Change value for variables in following code:

$CurtAtr  is  current attribute like color, size, etc
$attrVal is attribute value e.g. size has "small, medium, Large, etc"

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$read = $resource->getConnection('catalog_read');  
$read->fetchAll("SELECT ao.sort_order FROM eav_attribute_option_value as aov, eav_attribute_option as ao where value='$attrVal' and aov.option_id = ao.option_id and attribute_id=$CurtAtr limit 1");
```